# How to use time in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have small shell script where I'm checking time I got same time whereas I'm using sleep for 10 sec.

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +%H:%m:%S`
echo $date
sleep 10
echo $date
```

output:

> 07:10:48
>
> 07:10:48

output should be like this

> 07:10:48
>
> 07:10:58

Comment: You store date into a variable and echo it twice. You need to execute the date *command* twice. Either just run the command or make the variable a string, i.e. don't use backticks on the assignment

Comment: basically I will use that variable in log file and time will change in every execution.It is not possible I will store into variable and use in it.

Comment: Variables hold data; they *don't* execute code each time they are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the same variable (`date`)twice. Here is the fix:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +%H:%m:%S`
echo $date
sleep 10
date=`date +%H:%m:%S`
echo $date
```

And you'll get what you expected!

Comment: thanks 4 your reply I know that things I want call only one time this variable.

Answer (score 1):

DRY: use a function

```
mydate() { date +%T; }

mydate
sleep 10
mydate
```

Or, use it *like* a variable:

```
echo "current time is $(mydate)"
```

btw, `%m` is the month (10), `%M` is the minute.